Should I drop a semester due to medical reasons
I am currently in my undergraduate course and I have fractured my right collarbone and have been informed that I won't be able to write for at least a month and half.
Even in the best case I will be directly sitting for my mid semester without ever taking notes or practicing for my exams by hand. As my courses are math and physics intensive I am not sure how I will perform, I am worried this might dent my gradings.
Should I consider dropping a semester and maybe spend the remaining time of this semester after my recovery doing unofficial projects?

Ask your doctor and professor(s) about this. Talk to any disability office at the university for advice on how it can be compensated for. Talk to a physical therapist, perhaps. Ask a trusted advisor or faculty member for advice on a plan. It might be better to continue. It might be better to drop. But seek advice from experts with experience both with you and with such conditions. My choice might be different from yours. Heal. Don't be bored.

Aggree, especially re "Disability office". Also my uni I would suggest "academic advising", "Dean of students" and "incomplete"

Yes, I always refer students in situations like this to the disability office. They should be able to set you up with some extra time for tests (since writing with your non-dominant arm will be slower) and maybe notetaking. You'll still need to do the homework, of course, but a lot of people can learn to use their non-dominant arm well enough for that.


I am currently in my undergraduate course and I have fractured my right collarbone and have been informed that I won't be able to write for at least a month and half.

It will take you much less than that to become fairly proficient at writing with your left hand. I had an immobilized right arm at roughly your age and had to go through the same motions, literally. It wasn't a collarbone injury, though, so perhaps there are some special considerations for the use of the left arm for writing with a right-side collarbone injury? That would be my concern, so make sure you check that with your medical provider.
Of course there may be benefits to taking a semester-long break just using the collarbone injury as a convenient trigger. So this may have been a happy coincidence that gave you a reason to consider a break that perhaps would do you good for other reasons.

I am worried this might dent my gradings.

Start practicing to write with your left hand right away and don't worry about grades I'd say.
Humans are practically ambidextrous as long as they exercise both hands equally. Usually one hand "wins" because there is slight preference for it and it's a self-reinforcing cycle with high positive feedback. This means that the gains from learning to use a given hand are fairly quick - to the point that it easily outpaces the other, less-used hand, in terms of instantaneous dexterity. But it's not as if your other hand is somehow deficient. It's just out of practice. The motor centers that control it are just as capable as those in the other arm. Dexterity is about relatively small imbalances that, due to feedback, escalate into radical choices :)

Citation needed that humans are "practically ambidextrous". I think if this were the case then there would be no left handed people since there are many pressures (from shaking hands to using scissors) that would encourage and reinforce right handedness from an extremely young age. OP may be able to, relatively quickly, learn to write legibly with their left hand, but also they very much might not.
